# Text (plain, long) automatically has line break converted to <br>

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a field Text(plain, long) and have a custom template
which currently only outputs this field.

```
{{ content.field_testing }}
```

When the output is rendered, all the line breaks are converted to `<br>` I need  to remove. I could add some filters but I figure there must be a way to prevent it in the first place. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using a custom template, the quicker way is just to use the [`replace()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter.

```
{{ content.field_testing|replace({'<br>': '', '<br />': ''}) }}
```

The field formatter used in the case of a plain text field doesn't have settings, so you cannot decide if the formatter should output the `<br />` tags you want to remove. It would probably make sense in few cases, especially if you need to replace those `<br />` with other text, but somebody could argue that if you don't need them, you could just avoid entering new lines in the field.

The alternative would be implementing a different field formatter, but this is not as quicker as using a filter. If you just need this for this exact purpose, it sounds a bit excessive.

Comment: Thank you i have gone with this as it seems the simplest solution right now to just replace.

Comment: Note that inside a field template, item.content is an array and not a string, so I had to do the slightly more messy option of: `{{ item.content|render|replace({'<br>': '', '<br />': ''})|raw }}`. Probably better to just create a true "plain text" formatter (br's are really annoying if using `<pre>` or `<code>`...), but I was lazy and this was easier to without an extra module.

Answer (score 2):

The default FieldFormatter for Text(plain, long) is BasicStringFormatter, and it does this:

```
$elements[$delta] = [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '{{ value|nl2br }}',
    '#context' => ['value' => $item->value],
  ];
```

You could overwrite it without the nl2br.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i created a new formatter

```
<?php
  namespace Drupal\inception\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

  use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;
  use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;

  /**
   * Plugin implementation of the 'basic_string_no_br' formatter.
   *
   * @FieldFormatter(
   *   id = "basic_string_no_br",
   *   label = @Translation("Plain text No BR"),
   *   field_types = {
   *     "string_long",
   *   },
   * )
   */
  class BasicStringNoBrFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items,   $langcode) {
      $elements = [];

      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
          // The text value has no text format assigned to it, so the user input
          // should equal the output, including newlines.
          $elements[$delta] = [
              '#type' => 'inline_template',
              '#template' => '{{ value }}',//Plain value without nl2br
              '#context' => ['value' => $item->value],
          ];
      }

      return $elements;
  }
}
```